# How to write a php file with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new in File handling. So I was wondering how would I go about to write a php file with php?

Let's say I want to make a php script which creates a file which contains the following code:

**PHP File TO be Created**

```
<?php
$item = "takes a variable from current file and put it here";
?>
```

Let's say I have a php which took the following from my form:

**Code which takes a variable and writes it to another php file, exactly as it is**

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['shirts'];

//Code which writes to Php File above
?>
```

I have no idea how to do this. Please be very explicit when you explain.
Thanks :)

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

Comment: you want to use functions like `fwrite` etc so write contents to files. see that link above ^^

Comment: generally a bad idea to write a php file with php.

Comment: Generating executable php code based on user input - is very bad idea. Just saying.

Comment: @Shamil I've been reading about it, but I need a simpler explanation. I've already read the basics into that link you gave me an hour ago.

Comment: @Fratyr I want to create a config file actually which will contain Db infos, and that's the best way I'm thinking about it. Could you help?

Comment: See Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/14575253/1415724 although you will need to protect yourself by sanitizing input etc. Taken from **Related** >>>

Comment: Why would you like to write a php file with variables from user input. I strongly recommend using a database for this purpose.

Comment: Checking this out @Fred-ii-

Comment: Ok, and do read these two articles https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724 they will surely help.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$var='that';
file_put_contents('newfile.php','<?php echo "thisthat' . $var . '"; ?>');
```

Note that if `$var` is coming from user input in any way you will need to be *extremely* careful to sanitize it so a hacker can't just do anything he wants on your server.

Documentation for `file_put_contents` here: [php.net/file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents('fileToCreate.php', '<?php' . "\n" . '$item = "' . $item . '";' . "\n" . '?>')
```

viz here: [php.net/file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)